# Is there any way to plot three numerical variables and one categorical in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

[image]I tried to create a scatter plot with  three numerical variables, which are Longitude, Latitude and penetration rate. From the color in scatter plot I can have an idea about the intensity of the penetration rate. But I also want to add a filter of categorical column. So that when I apply filter on categorical column it gives me the scatter plot for that category only with color showing intensity for penetration rate.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason that you tagged this as R, Python, etc. when this was a Power BI problem?

Comment: btw both images are same.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your category column as a visual filter.